# grails - I need to define my validation at runtime

Tags: validation, grails, runtime

I have an idea to read an XML document from the database and generate simple CRUD screens (via Grails) based on the data defined.  My application will call RESTFul services to persist the data so I don't need Hibernate on the client side.  I have ideas about how to generate the UI but where I'm stumped is in how to perform the validation.

I'll have a single, generic domain/command object that contains only the fields that are common for all instances of this "runtime" data type.  All other fields are defined via the XML found in the database.  I need something like this:

```
String xml // defines the fields, constraints, UI information for this data type
def constraints = {
    callMyCustomValidator(obj)
}
```

and in my `callMyCustomValidator` method, I'll extract the xml for `obj` and perform my validation as needed.

Note: We have a working example of this in a different app (written in java/servlers/jsp) and without any formal "framework" this isn't difficult to do.  Why do I need this?  We need to add simple datatypes on the fly (via script) without a release.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) to add custom validation to your domain class. Just add this to some of your common fields.